# Series : dynamic transposition optimization

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I would like to convert a Pandas Series to transposed Dataframe, where number of key/values is dynamic. Then, transposed Dataframe must have dynamic number of columns also.

I succeeded using to_frame() and to_transpose() methods, but I would like to optimize my code.
More precisely, I need to use the reset_index() method and then drop the "index" created column which is useless... I supposed it can be better achieved.

Please find my current code:

```
current_case_details = row.to_frame().transpose().reset_index()
current_case_details.drop(columns=['index'], inplace=True)
print("CURRENT CASE DETAILS:\n{0}\n".format(current_case_details))
```

Please find an illustration of expected result : [picture of expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoNCe.png)

Do you have any solution to optimize my code using "standards" Pandas series/dataframes methods/options ?

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DataFrame.transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) + [DataFrame.set_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
new_df=serie.to_frame().T.reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

Example:

```
serie=pd.Series([1,2,3,'AA'],['c1','c2','c3','c4'],name='Value')
print(serie)

c1     1
c2     2
c3     3
c4    AA
Name: Value, dtype: object
```

---

```
new_df=serie.to_frame().T.reset_index(drop=True)
print(new_df)

  c1 c2 c3  c4
0  1  2  3  AA
```

Comment: Hello, the "row" variable is a Series (not Dataframe). So the proposed solution doesn't work (cf attached picture).

Comment: Then you are looking for reset_index(drop=True) . Please check the new solution:)